# jQuery grab height and run function only for this item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

I have a gallery of images, each of different sizes, and I want to vertically center an icon on the hovered image. I've been trying to solve this with the code below and I successfully grabbed all of the heights of the images, but I can't figure out how to apply only one specific height, the image hovered, into the equation and run the functions. The following is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var wrapper = $('.img-wrap', this); // Grab the wrapper, same as image size

    wrapper.prepend("<div class='cover'><img src='imgs/icons/search.png' alt='zoom into photo'></div>") // this is not so important

wrapper.each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    var $height = $this.height(); // Get height of Wrapper or Image (same size)
    var $marginHeight = ($height - 32) / 2; // Height of Wrapper - Icon Size (32px) and divided by two to only get one half

    console.log($height) // Check height
    console.log($marginHeight) // Check one half 


    // Main problem
    wrapper.hover(
        function() {
            $('.cover img', this).css({
                "marginTop": $marginHeight
            });
        });


    // this runs fine
    wrapper.mouseout(
        function() {
            $('.cover img', this).css({
                "marginTop": 0
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You know that passing **one** function to `.hover()` means it is run for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, right? http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover2 . Did you mean to use `wrapper.mouseenter(func...` and `wrapper.mouseleave(func...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.img-wrap')
        .prepend("<div class='cover'><img src='imgs/icons/search.png' class="cover_img" alt='zoom into photo'></div>")
        .on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
            var h = e.type == 'mouseenter' ? ($(this).height() - 32) / 2 : 0;
            $(this).find('.cover_img').css('margin-top', h);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxT8M/2/)